# Catenoid is bounded

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The 2-dimensional Catenoid is a complete noncompact surface in R^3, think about of higher dimensional analogue of Catenoid, why is it bounded by two hyperplanes? that's really anti-intuitive.

Comment: I got it, since the graph blows up at finite time in higher dimension.